# Do different URLs for the same resource cause SEO problems

Tags: model-view-controller, frameworks, seo

I am using a framework similar to codeIgniter and Zend FW. So URL structure is the same. Meaning  `/controller/action/etc....` However there are some cases when different URLs maps the same controller. This results in different urls having the (very similar) content and text.

For example these two urls map to the same page.

- /article/id/646478
- /book/754/review/

I am wondering; will this cause a SEO issue. Does anyone know how Google reacts to such cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duplicate content can impact your SEO performance.  It's quite useful to specify a **canonical** link which Google, Microsoft and Yahoo have agreed on the use of to help reduce duplicate content causing dilutions in listings.  A good read is [here](http://searchengineland.com/canonical-tag-16537).

Answer (score 1):

What was mentioned, and you should use keyword based URLs, not ID ones.

Instead of:
    * /article/id/646478
    * /book/754/review/

Use:
    * /brand-name/product
or
    * /category/brand-name/product

e.g.

domain.com/running/nike/cross-trainer-air-max